# copying actual drupal content to a different drupal site

Tags: nodes

I know that one can use the export link to copy a content type or a view to another drupal site. But if that content type has a lot of content, is there a way to also copy that over as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this with the [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) (export) and [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) (import) modules.

Comment: If I want to export taxamony term lists too, how would I do this?

Comment: Drupal 7 : [link](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv), Drupal 6 : [link](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_export), [link](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_xml). It depends on your drupal version / data format.

Answer (score 3):

It may be too late for this, but I needed the same thing and came across this thread so thought others might also. There's a new module called [Data Export Import](http://drupal.org/project/data_export_import) which does exactly what you need:

> The purpose of this module is to be able to export nodes, taxonomy
>   terms and users to data files and then be able to import these data
>   files into Drupal sites. There may be many uses for this module but
>   the main one would be that it can provide a way to export data from a
>   live Drupal site and then to import that live data into an updated
>   version of that site.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably looking for the [Node export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) module:

> This module allows users to export nodes and then import it into another Drupal installation, or on the same site.

The [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) and [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) modules might also be of interest.

Comment: My most recent adventure with node_export had me crying under my desk.  Let's just say it didn't go well.